# Disable word prediction in Macbook touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

There are plenty of questions on how to disable the touch bar on a Mac, but I am only interested in disabling the text prompts. I find them visually distracting and would like them removed, but do not wish to change the touchbar to only function keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text prediction can be disabled in `Settings > Keyboard > Text` and disabling `Touch Bar typing suggestions`.

[image]